# keep value when using data.table::fcase() instead of dplyr::case_when()

Tags: r, data.table

I want to take advantage of the fast data.table::fcase() instead of using dplyr::case_when(), but I don't know how to keep the value of a given row as the default (and not a fixed value)

Say you have

```
dt <- data.table(v1 = c("1","2", "3", NA))
```

Using dplyr's `case_when()`

```
dt %>%
  mutate( v2 = case_when(is.na(v1) ~ "0",
                         TRUE ~ v1))
```

you get the expected result

```
> dt %>%
+   mutate( v2 = case_when(is.na(v1) ~ "0",
+                          TRUE ~ v1))
     v1 v2
1:    1  1
2:    2  2
3:    3  3
4: <NA>  0
```

Using data.table's `fcase()`

```
dt[ , v2 := fcase(is.na(v1), "0",
                  default = v1)]
```

(or anything similar to that code) you get the error

```
> dt[ , v2 := fcase(is.na(v1), "0",
+                   default = v1)]
Error in fcase(is.na(v1), "0", default = v1) : 
  Length of 'default' must be 1.
```

I believe because `v1` is viewed as the full column `v1`

How do I fix it?

Comment: Not so easy to parse, from ?fcase `Logical conditions when1, when2, ..., whenN must all have the same length, type and attributes. Each value may either share length with when or be length 1.`

Comment: @jimrothstein that's certainly relevant, but the OP was using `default=`, and I believe the docs are not clear that it must be length-1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `data.table`-equivalent of `dplyr::case_when(TRUE ~ expr)` is `fcase(rep(TRUE, .N), expr)`.

```r
dt[ , v2 := fcase(is.na(v1), "0", rep(TRUE, .N), v1)]
#        v1     v2
#    <char> <char>
# 1:      1      1
# 2:      2      2
# 3:      3      3
# 4:   <NA>      0
```

But in this case, both `dplyr` and `data.table`'s "coalesce" function is a better fit for *that* logic:

```r
dt |>
  mutate(v2 = coalesce(v1, "0"))
#        v1     v2
#    <char> <char>
# 1:      1      1
# 2:      2      2
# 3:      3      3
# 4:   <NA>      0
dt[, v2 := fcoalesce(v1, "0")]
#        v1     v2
#    <char> <char>
# 1:      1      1
# 2:      2      2
# 3:      3      3
# 4:   <NA>      0
```

Comment: Thank you @r2evans. That is exactly what I was looking for!!

Also, thank you for suggesting coalesce() and fcoalesce(). These would be nice alternatives (as you pint out for this example). Unfortunately, my conditions and substitutions are more complex making these less appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You can also solve your problem as follow either using `fifelse` from data.table or the built-in functions `pmax`/`pmin`:

```
dt[, v2 := fifelse(is.na(v1), "0", v1)]
# or
dt[, v2 := pmax(v1, "0", na.rm=TRUE)]

#        v1     v2
#    <char> <char>
# 1:      1      1
# 2:      2      2
# 3:      3      3
# 4:   <NA>      0
```